# Detect center of laser line with sub-pixel accuracy

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, detection, subpixel

I am developing a simple 'laser line' scanner using C++ and OpenCV. So far I can detect
the center of the laser line with an accuracy of 1 pixel, so I have a starting point for a possible 'sub pixel' function/algorithm. *(the laser line is approx. 15-20pixels wide)*

Now I am interested into refining this to sub-pixel accuracy. I know OpenCV has some 
sub-pixel detection functions, but as far as I know these are only for detecting
corners.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd like to hear them.

*Some information;*

- System: *QT Framework, C++, OpenCV library*
- Camera; *Monochrome (no color), equipped with red filter*
- Image resolution; *2560 x 1920*
- Note: *Only 1 image will be analyzed for the laser line.*

Comment: what limits you to one pixel precision?

Comment: I want to output a series of (real world) coördinates which describes the laser line scan. Eventually it will be used for measuring purposes. 


In order to guarantee a maximum precision, I need to determine the center of the laser line in sub pixel accuracy.

Comment: I understand that. What isn't clear is what the problem is.

Comment: The problem: I am in search of an algorithm/function which is capable of refining my 'found laser line center points' (pixel level) to sub-pixel level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two basic methods that I have used with good results:

- Easy: on one frame, threshold and locate the region containing the image of the laser stripe, then fit a parabola to the raw pixel intensities in a small interval (5-7 pixels, depending on how well focused your are) around the intensity maximum, at each image row. Your fitting routine must have a robustifier, because outliers are likely, e.g. near scene region with a significant specular reflection.
- Harder, but more precise if your camera's framerate is high enough (or the beam moves slowly enough): Curless's [spacetime analysis](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/spacetime/spacetime_full.pdf).

A search for "subpixel laser fitting" returns several more recent results.

On the practical side, pay close attention to saturation: your exposure time (or lens aperture) should ensure that your sensor won't saturate even when the beam hits the lightest portions of the object surface. Searching for a peak in an area where the signal has been clipped by saturation is obviously pointless.

Focusing (and depth of field) are other areas to pay attention - a blurred image of the beam on the object surface will yield a biased peak.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that!
Currently experimenting with a Gaussian fit function to determine the centroid of the laser line on sub-pixel level. I'm still interested in suggestions tho ;)..

Comment: You should upvote/accept the answer if it matches your request. Thanks